# json.cpp:474:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, curl, error-handling, chatscript

I am trying to compile `ChatScript` but I get this error message:

> json.cpp:474:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

When I try `apt-get install curl` it says:

> curl is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.7).

I also tried to install `curl-devel` and `libcurl` but I get:

> E: Unable to locate package ...

Why this error happens and how can I fix it? I am using `Ubuntu-server 16.04 sunxi-arm7`.

Comment: Post your code. Tell us the compiler you are using. What command are you using to compile the code?

Comment: To answer in short, you need to provide the include path to the compiler at compile time using `-I` option. The include path should be the directory containing `curl.h`. To find `curl.h` file, execute `sudo find / -name "curl.h"`.